# Power set of a complement and complement of a power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,4\}$.
What is the

1)$\mathcal P(A \setminus B)$

2)$\{\mathcal P(A) \setminus \mathcal P(B)\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$.

I got 
$A\setminus B$ as $\{2\}$
$\mathcal P(A)$ as $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$\mathcal P(B)$ as $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{4\},\{1,4\}\}$

$\mathcal P(A \setminus B)$ as $\{\emptyset, \{2\}\}$

but I'm not sure how part b goes and how to encorporate "$\cup \{\emptyset\}$" term.

Comment: Well, do you mean $(P(A) \setminus P(B)) \cup \{\emptyset \}$ or $P(A) \setminus (P(B)) \cup \{ \emptyset \} )$?

Comment: sorry, my bad. i have edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as $A \setminus B$ is the set of all elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$, $P(A) \setminus P(B)$ is the set of all elements that are in $P(A)$ but not in $P(B)$.  So:

$$P(A) \setminus P(B) = \{ \{ 2 \}, \{ 1,2 \} \}$$

And therefore:

$$(P(A) \setminus P(B)) \cup \{ \emptyset \} = \{ \{ 2 \}, \{ 1,2 \} , \emptyset\}$$